# Store a string message after using onItemLongClick (Android)

Tags: android

I want to store the `fMessage` to the variable `favoritekafe` and return the `favoritekafe` after the `onItemLongClick` method ends.

Is that possible in any way?

OR can i accomplish with a different way to return a variable except true/false from "onItemLongClick" method?

Thats my code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView kafeteries;
String favoritekafe;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.coffee);

    if (favoritekafe==null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you don't have a favorite 
    caffe yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), favoritekafe, 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



    /* oi kafeteries se lista */
    kafeteries = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.kafeteries);

    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
 (MainActivity2.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.kafeteries_syros));

    kafeteries.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // mnmta TOAST otan kanw click kapoio stixeio tis listas */
    kafeteries.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int   position, long id) {
            String sMessage = "";
            switch(position) {
                case 0: sMessage = "Coffee and drinks with hospitable locals\nArea:Ermoupoli\nPhone:2281083354"; break;
                case 1: sMessage = "Coffee in the narrow streets of the city\nArea:Ermoupoli\nPhone:2281079225"; break;
                case 2: sMessage = "The smallest and most adorable coffee in town\nArea:Ermoupoli\nPhone:2281300880"; break;
                case 3: sMessage = "Coffee and snacks at the city's harbor\nArea:Ermoupoli\nPhone:2281076144"; break;
                case 4: sMessage = "The city's most famous café\nArea:Ermoupoli\nPhone:2281085337"; break;
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    // prospathia gia long clik add sta favorite kai save*/
    kafeteries.setLongClickable(true);
    kafeteries.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long id) {

            // prepei na vrw ena tropo na epistrefw kai to position gia na apothikevw tin agapimeni epilogi */


            String fMessage = "";
            switch(position) {
                case 0: fMessage = "Boheme del mar is your favorite caffe"; break;
                case 1: fMessage = "Jar is favorite caffe"; break;
                case 2: fMessage = "Kouchico is your favorite caffe"; break;
                case 3: fMessage = "Okio is your favorite caffe"; break;
                case 4: fMessage = "Plaza is your favorite caffe"; break;
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            final SharedPreferences prefs=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("settings",MODE_PRIVATE);
            prefs.edit().putString(favoritekafe,fMessage).commit();

            return true;
        }

    });


    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to return it? you can just equate it `favoritekafe=fMessage;` and onItemLongClick() will always return true/false.

Comment: Because i want every time this activity starts to have a toast. 
Depending on whether you had previously long clicked an item from the Listview or not. (sorry for my english, it's not my native)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function inside your class

```
void gotStringFromLongClick(String fMessage){
    favoritekafe=fMessage;
    // do anything else you want here
}
```

and call it like `gotStringFromLongClick(fMessage);` from outside `switch`

```
    String sMessage = "";
     switch(position) {
                case 0: sMessage = "Coffee and drinks with hospitable locals\nArea:Ermoupoli\nPhone:2281083354"; break;
                case 1: sMessage = "Coffee in the narrow streets of the city\nArea:Ermoupoli\nPhone:2281079225"; break;
                case 2: sMessage = "The smallest and most adorable coffee in town\nArea:Ermoupoli\nPhone:2281300880"; break;
                case 3: sMessage = "Coffee and snacks at the city's harbor\nArea:Ermoupoli\nPhone:2281076144"; break;
                case 4: sMessage = "The city's most famous café\nArea:Ermoupoli\nPhone:2281085337"; break;
            }
  gotStringFromLongClick(fMessage);
  // save value to preference
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
  editor.putString("data", fMessage);
  editor.commit();
```

Retrieve value in `onCreate`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.coffee);
    favoritekafe = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("data", null);
    if (favoritekafe==null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you don't have a favorite 
    caffe yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), favoritekafe, 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work.Every time i start this activity the "favoritekafe" is null

Comment: obviously at first , you have a value although you can persist value in `sharedpreference`

Comment: It works...!!!
Only when the "favoritekafe" is null the toast appear to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in SharedPreference file.
inside your onLongClickListener do this

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit()
.putString("fav_kafe", favoritekafe).commit();
```

then in onCreate before making the Toast load it to fa`favoritekafe`

like this

```
favoritekafe=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
.getString("fav_kafe", "nothing"); 
if (favoritekafe.equals("nothing") {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you don't have a favorite 
caffe yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), favoritekafe, 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```